# Can I tell if a Legion General spawns?

Tags: path-of-exile

In Path of Exile, you can find Timeless Monoliths that spawn legion members in stasis. Sometimes they have leader generals with them, but often they are at the back of the group.

Is there a way to tell if one spawned and if so in which direction it might be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example, the purple mist kinda flows

[image]

Here's another example with excellent paint arrows, it's easier to tell

[image]

Comment: Ah excellent, that's just what I was looking for